# Create assembly compatible with desktop, wp7 and monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios

So I'm trying to figure out how to create an assembly with core functionality which can be used with Windows Phone 7-, Desktop-, and Monotouch-enabled devices. How do I set this up in MonoDevelop?

If I create an assembly the usual way, I can't add it as a reference to my monotouch project, but can I add a monotouch-assembly to desktop or even wp7 devices?

As a side question. Has anyone ever tried cross-platform development where one guy sits on visual studio, and another sits on monodevelop? How does this work out? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to create a regular c# class library project with the shared code.  Then create a monotouch class library and add links to the code from the original class library.  Same done for monodroid project.

This way updating the .cs files in one project will update the others.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot compile the source code directly to an assembly that you can just link in projects for different platforms.

For example in Monotouch and Monodroid particularly and this is because it uses AOT (ahead of time) compiler to create the binary output.

Therefore all the SDK is linked within the "assembly" which in fact is a specific and tailored for the specific platform.

So to do that, you need to share the project as a source code, which works well across the platforms, if you follow some rules (like use Mono even on Windows, just to be sure).

Comment: Sure, but how do I do this in MonoDevelop? There is no "source-code" project here. All I want is to be able to link to a project that contains the core functionality, and that Monotouch or Monodroid or whatever, compiles this when building the monotouch-enabled project.

Comment: As usual, use the edit references - open the project, expand it, right click the project section References, and from menu select Edit References..., in the dialog box select the appropriate reference, be it the other project in the solution or external .NET assembly or core assembly - Package.

If you choose the .NET assembly, it must be compiled to the project you are building, if Monotouch project, then only Monotouch references can be added.

Comment: Unfortunatly, MonoDevelop won't let me add a non-monotouch reference to a monotouch project... So if I want a "core" assembly for all my UI's, i need to create a seperate library project for each with identical code? This is what I'm trying to avoid :S

Comment: That is what I tried to explain, you cannot do that. Only one project type and one deployment. Cannot mix Monodroid with Monotouch and vice versa...

Comment: Man, that is inconvinient. Well, thanks for your answer sir :)